# Integral of $m$ products of identical normal probability density functions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am looking for a closed form solution of the integral from $m$ products of identical normal distribution probability density functions (PDF's). The mean value $\bar{x}=0$ and $\sigma$ identical for all distributions. Giving:

$$p(m)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ {\frac {1}{\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {x}{\sigma }}\right)^{2}} \right]^m dx$$

Empirical with Wolfram Alpha [[WA]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281%2F%28a*sqrt%282*pi%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x%29%2Fa%29%5E2%29%29%5E3%20x%3D-inf%20to%20inf) after puzzling I found the following closed function:

$$p(m)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m} \cdot (\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi})^{(m-1)} }$$

I am looking for proof of this expression. The question is related to: [SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4055539/650339), this function fit's perfect my Monte Carlo simulations.

Comment: Edited question, was described to complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking to complicated initially. With help of the derivation normal distribution I was able to find the answer see: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

My question basically is:

$$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{\pi})^m} \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }  e^{-mx^{2}}\,dx$$

Define:

$$u=\sqrt{m}x$$
$$dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} du$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}(\sqrt{\pi})^m} \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }  e^{-u^{2}}\,du$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{m}(\sqrt{\pi})^m}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}(\sqrt{\pi})^{(m-1)}}$$